# Facebook Graph API does not return comments from a specific user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I am using the Graph API to retrieve the comments attached to a status update on a Facebook  Page using a URL of this form:

"https://graph.facebook.com/status-ID/comments?access_token=XXX"

The above URL does not return any of the comments from a specific user while comments from all other users posted before and after that user’s are returned. Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This user has modified their **Facebook Privacy Settings** in the section **How people bring your info to apps they use** so that while you can view their comments via Facebook directly, you cannot view that same info via a Facebook App.

Comment: I tested your diagnosis but that doesn’t seem to be the reason for the problem I’ve described :(. That is, the comments can still be retrieved by my application even when **all** options in **How people bring your info to apps they use** of the **Facebook Privacy Settings** section are ticked. I guess the reason is that there is no separate option to block the _comments_ although there are options for blocking _status updates_, _photos_, _links_, etc. Any other ideas?